# MVC3 autobinding to list of JSON objects is not working for the properties

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an array of JSON objects I am posting to a MVC3 controller.  The JSON seems to post fine based on the fiddler check I ran.  (included below)  The controller is accepting a custom class I setup to receive the JSON data.  That seems to work fine as well (debugger screenshot included below)  The issue is that the object properties don't seem to be autobinding like I would expect.  The names all match, I'm not sure the issue.

The jquery is below  (first click to add to the array, then click to post the data)

```
var removes = [];
var adds = [];

var transaction = {
    'adds': adds,
    'removes': removes
};

jQuery(".AddCardLink").click(function () {
            var card = [{
                Id: jQuery(this).attr("cardid"),
                Name: jQuery(this).attr("cardname")
            }];
            transaction.adds.push(card);
        })

jQuery("#btnSave").click(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/SaveTransactionLog",
                data: JSON.stringify(transaction),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                   alert("Test");
                }
            });
        });
```

This is the fiddler view of the sent data

[image: Fiddler]

The custom class and controller are below:

```
public class Card
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class JsonTransaction
{
     public List<Card> Adds { get; set; }
     public List<Card> Removes { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveTransactionLog(JsonTransaction transaction)
{ 
   return  Json()
}
```

Finally, here is the debugger look at the JsonTransaction, you can see the autobind setup the correct lists, but the Card in the list properties are empty.

[image]

If you stuck till the end, thanks!  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Argh!  After spending the whole weekend on this and finally posting on SO yesterday, I discovered my issue!

My Jquery I had an extra square bracket around my objects when I was adding them through onclick.  Removing the square brackets solved my issue.

```
jQuery(".AddCardLink").click(function () {
            var card = **[**{
                Id: jQuery(this).attr("cardid"),
                Name: jQuery(this).attr("cardname")
            }**]**;
            transaction.adds.push(card);
        })
```